# Improve throughput of ndb query over large data

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to perform some data processing in a GAE application over data that is stored in the Datastore. The bottleneck point is the throughput in which the query returns entities and I wonder how to improve the query's performance.

What I do in general:

- everything works in a task queue, so we have plenty of time (10 minute deadline).
- I run a query over the ndb entities in order to select which entities need to be processed.
- as the query returns results, I group entities in batches of, say, 1000 and send them to another task queue for further processing.
- the stored data is going to be large (say 500K-1M entities) and there is a chance that the 10 minutes deadline is not enough. Therefore, when the task is reaching the taskqueue deadline, I spawn a new task. This means I need an ndb.Cursor in order to continue the query from where it stopped.

The problem is the rate in which the query returns entities. I have tried several approaches and observed the following performance (which is too slow for my app):

**Use fetch_page() in a while loop.**

The code is straightforward

```
while has_more and theres_more_time:
 entities, cursor, more = query.fetch_page(1000, ...)
 send_to_process_queue(entities)
 has_more = more and cursor
```

With this approach, it takes 25-30 seconds to process 10K entities. Roughly speaking, that is 20K entities per minute. I tried changing the page size or the class of the frontend instance; neither made any difference in performance.

**Segment the data and fire multiple fetch_page_async() in parallel.**

[This approach is taken from here (approach C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11509368/best-practice-to-query-large-number-of-ndb-entities-from-datastore)

The overall performance remains the same as above. I tried with various number of segments (from 2 to 10) in order to have 2-10 parallel fetch_async() calls. In all cases, the overall time remained the same. The more parallel fetch_page_async() are called, the longer it takes for each one to complete. I also tried with 20 parallel fetches and it got worse. Changing the page size or the fronted instance class did not have and impact either.

**Fetch everything with a single fetch() call.**

Now this is the least suitable approach (if not unsuitable at all) as the instance may run out of memory, plus I don't get a cursor in case I need to spawn to another task (in fact I won't even have the ability to do so, the task will simply exceed the deadline). I tried this out of curiosity in order to see how it performs and I observed the best performance! It took 8-10 seconds for 10K entities, which is roughly be 60K entities per minute. Now that is approx. 3 times faster than fetch_page(). I wonder why this happens.

**Use query.iter() in a single loop.**

This is match like the first approach. This will make use of the query iterator's underlying generator, plus I can obtain a cursor from the iterator in case I need to spawn a new task, so it suits me. With the query iterator, it fetched 10K entities in 16-18 seconds, which is approx. 36-40K entities per minute. The iterator is 30% faster than fetch_page, but much slower that fetch().

For all the above approaches, I tried F1 and F4 frontend instances without any difference in Datastore performance. I also tried to change the batch_size parameter in the queries, still without any change.

A first question is why do fetch(), fetch_page() and iter() behave so differently and how to make either fetch_page() or iter() do equally well as fetch()? And then another critical question is whether these throughputs (20-60K entities per minute, depending on api call) are the best we can do in GAE.

I 'm aware of the MapReduce API but I think it doesn't suit me. AFAIK, the MapReduce API doesn't support queries and I don't want to scan all the Datastore entities (it's will be too costly and slow - the query may return only a few results). Last, but not least, I have to stick to GAE. Resorting to another platform is not an option for me. So the question really is how to optimize the ndb query.

Any suggestions?

Comment: For your processing I don't see any real reason to use fetch_page , just use fetch with a limit and a cursor you have no need for going backwards, or knowing if their might be some addition records  (which is an overhead that fetch_page is adding).  Ultimately this is what the is used under the hood.

Comment: I 'm not sure I follow you. How can you get a Cursor from fetch()? You can limit the results in fetch but the returned result is a only list of entities. I don't see a way to get a Cursor after calling fetch(). There is also the offset parameter but, according to the docs, it's not efficient.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I was thinking of db not ndb.

Comment: I´m having the same performance problems, trying to find a more general solution [here #26759950](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26759950/gae-aggregate-work-results-from-tasks-for-a-gae-query-performance-issue)

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is interested, I was able to significantly increase the throughput of the data processing by re-designing the component - it was suggested that I change the data models but that was not possible.

First, I segmented the data and then processed each data segment in a separate taskqueue.Task instead of calling multiple fetch_page_async from a single task (as I described in the first post). Initially, these tasks were processed by GAE sequentially utilizing only a single Fx instance. To achieve parallelization of the tasks, I moved the component to a specific GAE module and used basic scaling, i.e. addressable Bx instances. When I enqueue the tasks for each data segment, I explicitly instruct which basic instance will handle each task by specifying the 'target' option.

With this design, I was able to process 20.000 entities in total within 4-5 seconds (instead of 40'-60'!), using 5 B4 instances.

Now, this has additional costs because of the Bx instances. We 'll have to fine tune the type and number of basic instances we need.

Answer (score 0):

The new experimental [Data Processing](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/dataprocessing/) feature (an AppEngine API for MapReduce) might be suitable.  It uses automatic sharding to execute multiple parallel worker processes, which may or may not help (like the Approach C in the other linked question).

Comment: AFAIK, the MapReduce Api doesn't work with queries. It scans the entire Datastore and I want to avoid that all the time. The query may only match a few records, there's no need to scan all entities.

Answer (score 0):

Your comment about "no need to scan all entities" triggers the thought that custom indexes could help your queries.  That may entail schema changes to store the data in a less normal form.

Design a solution from the output perspective - what the simplest query is that produces the required results, then what the entity structure is to support such a query, then what work is needed to create and maintain such an entity structure from the current data.