# How to quickly retrieve a number of rows from data store?

Tags: performance, google-app-engine

In an Python GAE application that I'm working on, we need to retrieve n rows from storage, and we are running into performance issues for n > 100. We expect n to be less than 10000 is most cases.

So let's consider a simple model:

```
class MyEntity(ndb.Model):
    field1 = nbd.StringProperty()
    field2 = ndb.StringProperty()
    #...
    fieldm = ndb.StringProperty()
    # m is quite large, maybe ~ 30. Stored strings are short - in the order of 30 characters or less
```

I've populated the data store with some data, and got really bad performance using plain `fetch()`. I've since removed all filters, and just trying to get a number of entities seems to get very bad performance (as compared with what I would expect, say, for any common SQL deployment. I know that we shouldn't compare GAE to SQL, but just getting flat rows down - I would expect to be more performant, not less). Here's what I've tried:

- The simplest approach `MyEntity.all().fetch(n)`. This scales linearly with `n`, which is expected. Although I didn't expect it to take 7s for `n = 1000`.
- Trying to coerce `fetch()` with any reasonable `batch_size` degrades performance further. I've tried values ranging from 1 to 1000.
- Doing `keys_only` gives an order of magnitude improvement.
- Doing  a query manually (`through ndb.Query`), and getting out just a single field gives a small improvement, in the order of 1.2.
- Doing a `fetch_async(n)` and waiting gives exactly same performance.
- Splitting the job into `p` parts, then doing `fetch_async(n/p, offset=...)` and then waiting and joining all futures - gives at best same performance, at worst - much worse performance.
- Similar story with `fetch_page()`

I've also tried using `db` instead of `ndb`, and the results are pretty much the same. So, now I'm not sure what to do? Is there a way to get half decent performance for `n` in the order of 10000? Even simplifying my entities to single fields, the performance is too poor. I expect the entire payload uncompressed to be roughly 1 mb. Downloading 1mb in over a minute is clearly unacceptable.

I am seeing this issue live, but for performance testing I'm using remote api. My question is similar to this question on SO: [Best practice to query large number of ndb entities from datastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11509368/best-practice-to-query-large-number-of-ndb-entities-from-datastore). They didn't seem to find a solution, but it was asked 4 years ago, maybe there is one now.

Comment: What do you see in the logs for this request?

Comment: What do you want to do after you fetch the rows?

Answer (score 1):

If you only need a subset of the fields for the model, then look into [Projection Queries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/projectionqueries#Python_Using_projection_queries_in_Python)

Comment: There's a performance benefit in getting a lot of queries, but I'm looking for a general solution that would boost performance of getting n~10000 rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can get better performance depending on what you need to do with the retrieved data. For example, using as you mentioned `_async` [*documentation here*](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/async). You may retrieve a subset of the data, say first 100, then call `_async` on the next subset of 100 records while processing the first data batch since `_async` is non blocking. By the end of your precessing, use `.get_result()` to retrieve the second batch results and start processing on its data while calling the third batch using `_async`...etc.